# How to change label of \pgfcalendarweekdayshortname?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I will build the calendar in other langauge (thai) with tikzlibrary. I can change the `\pgfcalendarmonthname` but the `\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname`, I can't. The following code has errors.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calendar}
    \usepackage{translator}
    \begin{document}
    % % % % % % % % %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% % % % %This is good.
    \def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%
    \translate{\ifcase#1\or JJJ\or FFF\or MMM\or AAA\or
    MAY\or JJU\or JJY\or AAU\or SSS\or OOO\or
    NNN\or DDD\fi}}
    % %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% % % % % % % % % % % % % % %This is errors.
    \def\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname#1{%
    \translate{\ifcase#1\or SU\or MN\or TU\or WE\or
    TH\or FR\or SA\fi}}
    % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \calendar
    [dates=2013-09-01 to 2013-09-last,
    day list downward,
    month label left,
    day code={\node[name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname,
    every day]{\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}\
    \tikzdaytext};},
    every month/.append style={anchor=base east,xshift=-2em}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens because `\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday` uses zero-based indexing (Monday = 0), but you haven't defined the appropriate case in your `\ifcase` statement. Use

```
\def\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname#1{%
\translate{\ifcase#1 MN\or TU\or WE\or
TH\or FR\or SA \or SU\fi}}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\usepackage{translator}
\begin{document}
% % % % % % % % %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% % % % %This is good.
\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%
\translate{\ifcase#1\or JJJ\or FFF\or MMM\or AAA\or
MAY\or JJU\or JJY\or AAU\or SSS\or OOO\or
NNN\or DDD\fi}}
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% % % % % % % % % % % % % % %This is errors.
\def\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname#1{%
\translate{\ifcase#1 MN\or TU\or WE\or
TH\or FR\or SA \or SU\fi}}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\calendar
[dates=2013-09-01 to 2013-09-last,
day list downward,
month label left,
day code={\node[name=\pgfcalendarsuggestedname,
every day]{\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}    \tikzdaytext};},
every month/.append style={anchor=base east,xshift=-2em}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Monday is day 0? That's really weird.

Comment: @egreg: Do you mean the zero-based indexing, or the fact that the week starts on Monday? The latter is [in line with the ISO specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) (and zero-based indexing is not really that weird, is it?)

Comment: @Jake So it's the ISO to be weird; not the first instance, IMHO. Sunday should be day 0, if history is taken into account, or day 1, according to other traditions.

Comment: @egreg I think that's only respected in US calendars nowadays. If you change the settings of calendars from EU to US, sunday comes first. How do I know? because I have to use Outlook at work. Somebody save me